# Make prediction on new data set in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction

I have made a model based on a subset selection method and my goal is to predict attendance for future football/soccer matches.

In my training data I have 236 observations. I need to predict on 3 future matches that currently have NA in their data, since the matches have not occured yet.

So essentially I used the training data including the 3 matches for my new data set, which the model should predict the attendance for the 3 matches. This comes down to the new data set having 239 observation.

I have tried different methods with help from chatGTP, but when introducing the new data set, it does not take the 3 match into account, because the training was only done 236 observation.

How can I predict the 3 matches based on the model I have made?

My code below: Dataset used: https://file.io/hiXS1FGDJDxK

```
    sl_klar = read.csv("data/fulldata 1.csv")

# Removing covid period

    start_dato <- as.Date("2020-03-07")
    slut_dato <- as.Date("2021-04-16")

    sl_klar <- sl_klar[!(sl_klar$Dato >= start_dato & sl_klar$Dato <= slut_dato), ]

# Filter NA values out and only looking at home statistics

    sl_klar <- sl_klar %>%
    filter(Hjemmehold == "Viborg FF") %>%
    na.omit()

# Removing irrelevant variables

    sl_klar = sl_klar %>%
    dplyr::select(-Fugtighed, -Fugtighed.den.sidste.time, -Vindhastighed, -Nedbør.sidste.time, 
    -Dagtype, -indbyggertal, -Populær.kanal,
    -Runde, -Helligd., -Temperatur, -ID, -Dato, -Tid,- Hjemmehold, -Udehold, -Hjemmeholdsmål, 
    -Udeholdsmål, -Ugedag, -Synlighed, -X, -Form)

# Best subset and K-Fold

    predict.regsubsets <- function(object, newdata, id, ...) {
    form <- as.formula(object$call[[2]])
    mat <- model.matrix(form, newdata)
    coefi <- coef(object, id = id)
    xvars <- names(coefi)
    mat[, xvars] %*% coefi
    }

    set.seed(5)
    train <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(sl_klar), replace = TRUE)

    test <- (!train)

    train
    test

    sl_train = sl_klar[train,]
    sl_test = sl_klar[test,]

# Training regsubsets() on training data:

    regfit.best <- regsubsets(Tilskuere ~ .,
    data = sl_train, nvmax = 4)

    k <- 10
    n <- nrow(sl_train)
    set.seed(5)
    folds <- sample(rep(1:k, length = n))
    dim(sl_train)[2]  
    cv.errors <- matrix(NA, k, 4,
    dimnames = list(NULL, paste(1:4)))
    cv.errors

# Initialising val.errors and used to store

# validation set errors in.

    for (j in 1:k) { # her gennemløbes alle folds
    best.fit <- regsubsets(Tilskuere ~ .,
    data = sl_train[folds != j, ],
    nvmax = 4)
    for (i in 1:4) {
    pred <- predict(best.fit, sl_train[folds == j, ], id = i)
    cv.errors[j, i] <-
    mean((sl_train$Tilskuere[folds == j] - pred)^2)
    }
    }

    mean.cv.errors <- apply(cv.errors, 2, mean)

    mean.cv.errors
    par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
    plot(mean.cv.errors, type = "b")
    which.min(mean.cv.errors)

# Fitting model to training data

    reg.best <- regsubsets(Tilskuere ~ ., data = sl_train,
    nvmax = 3)
    coef(reg.best, 3)

    pred_best_subset <- predict(reg.best, sl_test, id = 3)

    mse_best_subset <- mean((sl_klar[test,]$Tilskuere - pred_best_subset)^2)

# Prediction --------------------------------------------------------------

    pred.data = read.csv("data/fulldata 1.csv")

# Remove covid period

    start_dato <- as.Date("2020-03-07")
    slut_dato <- as.Date("2021-04-16")

    pred.data <- pred.data[!(pred.data$Dato >= start_dato & pred.data$Dato <= slut_dato), ]

# # Filter and only looking at home statistics

    pred.data = pred.data %>%
    filter(Hjemmehold == "Viborg FF")

# Removing NA values except the last 3 rows (the 3 matches we want to predict)

    pred.data <- pred.data %>%
    filter(
    !is.na(Tilskuere) | row_number() %in% (n() - 2):n(),
    across(everything(), ~!is.na(.) | row_number() %in% (n() - 2):n())
    )

# Removing irrelevant variables

    pred.data <- pred.data %>%
    dplyr::select(-Fugtighed, -Fugtighed.den.sidste.time, -Vindhastighed, -Nedbør.sidste.time, 
    -Dagtype, -indbyggertal, -Populær.kanal,
    -Runde, -Helligd., -Temperatur, -ID, -Dato, -Tid,- Hjemmehold, -Udehold, -Hjemmeholdsmål, 
    -Udeholdsmål, -Ugedag, -Synlighed, -X, -Form)

# Now the 2 data set should have same structure except 3 rows we need to predict in the new data set

    > str(pred.data)
    > 'data.frame': 239 obs. of  5 variables:
    > $ Tilskuere           : int  3164 6984 4259 4563 4438 6655 3059 4610 4472 2952 ...
    > $ Superliga.1.Division: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    > $ Ferieuger           : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    > $ Modstander.Type     : int  2 0 2 1 2 0 2 1 2 2 ...
    > $ Tid.på.dagen        : int  0 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...

    > str(sl_klar)
    > 'data.frame': 236 obs. of  5 variables:
    > $ Tilskuere           : int  3164 6984 4259 4563 4438 6655 3059 4610 4472 2952 ...
    > $ Superliga.1.Division: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    > $ Ferieuger           : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    > $ Modstander.Type     : int  2 0 2 1 2 0 2 1 2 2 ...
    > $ Tid.på.dagen        : int  0 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...

    - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:16] 25 28 32 39 90 92 109 110 111 132 ...
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:16] "25" "28" "32" "39" ...

# Predicting attendance for the 3 matches

    predict_attendance <- predict(reg.best, pred.data, id = 3)
```

Snippet of outcome. It exclude the 3 matches (only up to row 236)

```
226 5307.990
227 3891.372
228 5307.990
229 6724.609
230 6724.609
231 3283.656
232 3891.372
233 3891.372
234 6724.609
235 5307.990
236 3283.656
```

Comment: I get "Deleted
The transfer you requested has been deleted." when attempting to access the data.

Comment: @IRTFM Sorry, I think the link expired. I have uploaded a new one.